# How to correctly pass props to a component with RxJS in Angular 4?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, angular-components

Here is my component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'bc-goods-detail',
  template: `
    <span>good id: {{good?.id}}</span>
    <input [value]="good?.name" (input)="onInput($event)" />
    <button (click)="onClick()">Save</button>
  `,
  styles: []
})
export class GoodsDetailComponent {
  @Input() good: Good;
  @Output() save  = new EventEmitter<Good>();

  onClick() {
    this.save.emit(this.good);
  }

  onInput ($event) {
    this.good.name = $event.target.value;
  }
}
```

When I change the name in input and then I am pressing save button and `this.good` is NOT CHANGED good. It is old `good`, like it was passed to the component.

I started to debug the problem. I added `onInput` handler. I found that when I do this instruction: `this.good.name = $event.target.value;` I get this error in console:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'name' of object '#<Object>'
    at GoodsDetailComponent.webpackJsonp.435.GoodsDetailComponent.onInput (goods-detail.ts:24)
```

Here is usage of the component:

```
<bc-goods-detail
  [good]="selectedGood$ | async"
  (save)="onSave($event)"
></bc-goods-detail>
```

Here is how I receive data for this component:

```
/*…*/
selectedGood$: Observable<Good>;

constructor(private store: Store<fromRoot.State>) {
  /*…*/
  this.selectedGood$ = store.select(fromRoot.getGoodSelectedEntity);
}
```

Here is the full code of container component: [here](https://github.com/sharikovvladislav/ng2-goods-list-ngrx/blob/feature/add-dispatch-ability-to-detail-component/src/app/containers/goods-container.ts#L28).

Thoughts: I think the problem is because Observable returns immutable structure. I don’t think it is totally bad idea, but how to handle it?

I am trying to get same behaviour there: http://plnkr.co/edit/gdxEcSvC0v6JwoLEZDkJ?p=preview. It does not reproduce. I think this is because

How to solve my problem? I don’t want to get such error. When I press save I want `this.good` to contain mutated object. How to achieve this?

Comment: Did you solved this?

Comment: Not sure. I have researching about reactive forms in my todolist. Some says that they can help there too. Your suggestion is one of the answers as I think. If I will get more variants I will improve your answer. Give me some time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a copy of the original object in your presentation component and emit the value of that copy onClick of save. After emiting the mutated object, the action that you dispatch should store it as payload and the reducer should take care of replacing the old object with the mutated one. That is at least the approach that I use in my presentation components :)

For example:

```
export class GoodsDetailComponent {
  private _original: Good;
  goodClone: Good; // use this inside of the component template
  @Input('good')
  get good(){return this.goodClone;}
  set good(value:  Good){
    this.goodClone= //generate a clone of the object
    this._original = value;
  }

  @Output() 
  save  = new EventEmitter<Good>();

  onClick() {
    this.save.emit(this.goodClone);
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any examples of the code? Is it best practise? Did you try any other approaches?

Comment: take a look here, a similar approach is used:  http://onehungrymind.com/build-better-angular-2-application-redux-ngrx/

Comment: Yes this approach obviously works... I have similar approach now but implemented with ngOnChanges. Well it looks awfull to have two properties. One is an input and another is local copy. Is it best practise? Component body becomes dirtier if I go this way... Thats not cool. Of course thank you for your answer. Upvote

Comment: why awful? In fact it adds funtionality: it allows to easily detect changes if u store the original object in a private variable by just making a (deep) object comparision

Comment: Ye I understand the profits... But I have to store one more variable for each input prop. It does not looks good in my opinion. I could have 1 string, but I have 4 and now I have to operate with 2 entities...

Comment: Welp, thats what you get when you work with immutable objects and ngrx. A basic principle of the framework (and redux I think) is that you cant mutate the app state by something different than dispatching an action, ergo you cant bind the state or parts of it to input fields directly

Comment: Well okay. It is just my opinion. If you suggest this approach then you say you have experience with it, right? And it was not bad If you still use it. Am I correct?

Comment: Sadly I cant showcase the mid size app where I used ngrx, is not open source. But yes, I used the deep clone approach whenever I needed to bind part of the state to a form or similar.

Comment: Well... Another point. OK what is the best practise to know this additional variable? I want api of the component (html signature) to be clear. So I don't want to change the input property name. Another point is I want inner template of the component to be clear too. With two variables I have do find some workaround, so template will be clear too. My be something like _ before name of the variable so template will be still readable. What do you think?

Comment: Edited my anwer. _ as preffix is normally for private variables. The name of the cloned object is your decission

Comment: You are right about _. Yes I understand that I can name it as I prefer. I just asked what do you use. Is the code in the answer is example how you used it?

Comment: Yup, the only thing that I didnt posted is the way I clone and compare the objects. But that isnt so relevant to your question I think

Comment: By the way how you do it? Is `{ ...objectToClone }` is enough? Or `Object.assign({}, objectToClone)`. Eh :( Is this only one correct way to solve my problem? This solution is not elegant :( I have to add 2-nd variable for each input...

Comment: If the input is a POJO you can simply use Object.assign(...). If the object that you pass through @input is part of the app state, you cant directly change it, you have to clone it. There is no way to avoid this. You will have a clone for every object that you want to change through the UI