# ngrx: should component comprising form tag be presentational or container?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, ngrx

I try following concept of [presentational and container](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0) components.

The scenario is simple. There are some presentational component comprising form tag and some container component interacting with Store.

```
@Component({
    selector: "presentational",
    template: 
`
<form>
    <input [(ngModel)]="model.name" />
    <button (click)="onSubmit()">Send</button>
</form>
`,
})
export class PresentationalCmp { 
    private model: Model;
    @Output() emitter = new Emitter<Model>();
    onSubmit() {
        this.emitter.emit(this.model);
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: "container",
    template: "<presentational (emitter)="addModel($event)"></presentational>"
})
export class ContainerCmp {
    addModel(model: Model){ 
        this.store.dispatch(..) //send model to server
    }
}
```

I find such approach logical. But there is one obvious issue. My PresentationalCmp is depended from some Model type(this type is used by Store actions). It's wrong, but the component need to be aware about Model type as it binds properties (name, ... etc) with input tags.

To additional my real "PresentationalCmp" need to be aware about some Store enum (it consists of values for select html tag).

So does it mean that the component comprising form tag in its template should be container, not presentational?

Comment: maybe related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44533046/how-to-correctly-pass-props-to-a-component-with-rxjs-in-angular-4/44533249#44533249 ?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo as I understand from that answer it is nothing awful if presentational cmp be aware about some Store type, or not (type Good in that answer)? So my question is about it. Always presentational  is decribed as "component knows nothing about Store"

Comment: At the end of the day, your specific app's needs should outweigh rigid adherence to certain conventions. While separating out view components from smart components makes sense as a general principle, there are definitely times where it makes sense to make an exception to the rule. My advice would be not to overthink it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is ment with “knows nothing about the store“ is that the store or any other store related info isnt injected through the constructor. So the only way for the dumb component to get/send info is through the input/output properties.

Using interfaces/classes that are know to the store is ok, specially if they represent entitites of your data model. Why? Well, typescript! Normally your store should only contain POJOs, which you can define by an interface. In this case is, again, completely normal to use the POJO interface to pass data around.